# NN prediction of fault duration time

Tags: neural-networks, predictive-models, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working on developing a neural network (NN) to predict the duration (in seconds) of a fault. However, I've encountered a couple of challenges:

Model Performance: My neural network seems to be predicting near the average fault duration, and the loss is currently high (over 10,000). For instance, with previous data:

Fault type: xyz
Duration (y in seconds): 180
In real-life scenarios:

Fault type: xzas
Duration (y): Needs prediction

Active Fault Constraint: In the next phase, I want the model to consider an ongoing fault with its elapsed duration. The prediction should be greater than the elapsed time. For example, if a fault has been active for 50 seconds, the model's prediction should be more than 50 seconds for the total duration.

Could you provide guidance on addressing these issues? Specifically, how can I improve the model's accuracy and incorporate the constraint for active faults?